# magento tries to install after migration

Tags: magento

As in topic.

I moved all my magento files to another server, moved mysql database, changed adresses in mysql and changed mysql password etc. in local.xml and magento tries to install itself.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

If you've confirmed all your database connections are valid and the data is sound the only other recommendation I can make is to clear everything inside /var.

That is all that should be required to move it. [Look at this question for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762090/how-do-i-transfer-a-local-magento-install-onto-my-live-server).

Comment: check for database name in local.xml

Comment: Simple But i badly missed this point .. and screwed up for 1 hr