# How to make Magento as my sub website?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I managed to move my magento store from my **localhost** to my **live server**, following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762090/how-do-i-transfer-a-local-magento-install-onto-my-live-server).

However, I have an unconventional folder structure how I run my **main website** and **magento website**. For instance,

This is the structure for my main website,

```
bin/
core/
local/
index.php
```

And I just want the magento system to be my **sub 'website'** as my webstore, so I keep all my magento files into `bin/store/`. And for this reason, all my images that I uploaded to `wysiwyg/` don't work anymore - they are not displayed on screen anymore.

Also, the links with url rewrite are not working anymore too, for instance,

http://store.helloworld.com/wine/

I will get,

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time
>   the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this
>   error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log. Apache Server at store.argenties.com Port 80

Any ideas how I can fix these two problems?

Comment: Check your apache/nginx logs, this is a server configuration issue, you need to configure you subdomain to point at ./bin/store/. Have you reindexed your website from the shell? Also could be a .htaccess problem

Comment: where can I check my apache/nginx logs? I have configured my subdomain to point to bin/store/ already.

Comment: `Have you reindexed your website from the shell? ` - how can I do that?

Comment: php shell/indexer.php --reindexall from command line. Depends on your server host which is GoDaddy so yeah good luck with that, that are notoriously bad, google GoDaddy and Magento and get reading, but really you should move your Magento hosting to a proper solution.

Comment: can you please recommend which hosting is good for Magento? Thanks.