# Copying a Magento Installation to Another Local Machine

Tags: php, mysql, magento, wamp

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO AND WHAT'S BLOCKING ME**

I have a Magento installation on a WAMP server in localhost and I'm trying to move that installation over to another machine running a localhost WAMP server as well. I'm encountering some difficulties, because when I point the browser to the appropriate directory, I get the following error:

[image]

**WHAT I'VE DONE**

To clone the installation to the second machine, these are the steps I took:

- I setup a WAMP server on the second machine.
- I copied all the project files into the `www` directory.
- I then copied all the database files from the `wamp/bin/mysql/mysqlX.X.XX/data/` to the same directory on the second machine.

**HOW I TRIED RESOLVING THIS**

I tried resolving the above error by renaming the `local.xml.sample` file in the `magento/errors/` directory to `local.xml`. But when I did that, I encountered this next error:

[image]

**FULL TEXT OF THE ERROR**

This is the full text of the error:

```
Error in file: "C:\wamp\www\NAME-OF-PROJECT\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\sql\core_setup\install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.core_resource' doesn't exist

Trace:
0 C:\wamp\www\NAME-OF-PROJECT\magento\includes\src\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
1 C:\wamp\www\NAME-OF-PROJECT\magento\includes\src\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.4')
2 C:\wamp\www\NAME-OF-PROJECT\magento\includes\src\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.4')
3 C:\wamp\www\NAME-OF-PROJECT\magento\includes\src\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
4 C:\wamp\www\NAME-OF-PROJECT\magento\includes\src\__default.php(20768): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
5 C:\wamp\www\NAME-OF-PROJECT\magento\includes\src\__default.php(20694): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
6 C:\wamp\www\NAME-OF-PROJECT\magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
7 C:\wamp\www\NAME-OF-PROJECT\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
8 {main}
```

**MY DATABASE TABLES**

Here's a snapshot from phpMyAdmin of the tables I have loaded:

[image]

**PLEASE HELP ME TROUBLESHOOT THIS**

I'm unsure why I'm getting this error and why Magento is unable to locate the table. Does it assume that there's a table prefix? If it does, where can I change that? Any help to successfully install a copy of this site onto another local machine would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to import all the tables to new machine for your magento.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762090/how-do-i-transfer-a-local-magento-install-onto-my-live-server

Comment: @TBI Isn't that already done when I drop the database files in the `data` directory? If I open phpMyAdmin, I can see the tables.

Comment: @VinodVT This isn't for a production server. Just a simple localhost setup.

Comment: Instead of moving database files try to export and import manually. This may fix your problem.

Comment: @Elavarasan - I tried this and it worked. Post your solution as an answer and I'll upvote it and mark it "correct". Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shmuli, Normally the moving databases (moving `data` directory from Mysql) should be worked. I didn't faced like this problem, and I have did many times. But in your case, I don't know exactly what is the problem. As for my knowledge this problem encountered by the log files. Mysql server creates some log files in your `data` directory.

That's like `ib_logfile0` , `ib_logfile1` in latest Mysql server. In old mysql server the log file should be like this `mysql-bin.xxxx`. For more information go **[link-1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29748/large-files-in-wamp-bin-mysql-mysql5-5-24-data-directory)**. and **[link-2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47046/why-do-the-mysql-bin-log-files-still-exist-after-a-purge-or-flush)**  You need to clear this before moving databases. Don't worry Mysql sever will create again those files.

And anyway direct export and import will solve this. For fast export, import (some magento database files may be very huge. It depends your store's catalog) try to use command line.

**For export:**

```
mysql -u root -p Db-name > Db-name.sql
```

(root is username)

after entered the password you will be get your database.

**For import:**

```
mysql -u root -p Db-name < Db-name.sql
```

(Db-name.sql -> give the sql file path)

That's it, any doubt please comment here.

Answer (score 3):

if the location or the credentials of you database have been changed, you need to change them as well in the app/etc/local.xml

if the urls of your installation have changed, you need to change them as well in core_config_data. the same for cookies domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I had encounter this problem once. From what i have done:

1: This path C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\tablename try to delete everything in these folder.

2: Past your new magento to the wamp folder and do what you do again it might work.